# "Ex's and Oh's" by Elle King- What is "Oh's"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

What does "Oh's" mean in the pop song "Ex's and Oh's" by Elle King? http://www.metrolyrics.com/exs-ohs-lyrics-elle-king.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple possible interpretations [according to contributors on Genius](http://genius.com/7931401):

> - The metaphorical x’s (hugs) and o’s (kisses) of the relationships
>     haunt her, symbolizing her running away from any actually feelings
>     developed in the process. “XO” is a common way to sign off in love
>     letters, or if you’re gossip girl.
> - Her ex’s and oh’s spark memories of a more sexual nature, which we
>     can presume the “oh’s” to be the orgasms she gave, to whom became her
>     “ex’s”.
> - Ex’s and oh’s also lend themselves to X’s and O’s of the
>     tic-tac-toe variety, thus reinforcing how she treats her relationships
>     like a game.

Comment: I always thought of it in the second context.

Comment: The phrase “they want me / to make them O” seems unambiguous.